# Any way to definitively determine the products of deuterium-deuterium fusion?

Tags: nuclear-physics, fusion

I was doing some reading and came across these two reactions:

$D + D \rightarrow \:^3He + n + 3.27 MeV$

and:

$D + D \rightarrow \:^3H + H + 4.03 MeV$

(from here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/NucEne/fusion.html)

My questions are: Is there any way to determine which of these reactions will occur based on the conditions those atoms are under? If so, how? If not, then it's entirely random? My end goal here is to get a number for the net energy output of D-D fusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two reactions are nearly equally probable. There is no way to favor one over the other.

As the comment by @JonCuster indicates, the above answer is not quite right.  Thanks Jon for providing the appropriate link.

Comment: While indeed 'nearly equal', they are in fact not quite equal and the branching ratio is a function of center-of-mass energy. https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0029-5515/32/4/I07/meta has the relevant fits. Below 15keV in the CM frame, the D(D,P)T reaction is favored, by 400keV in the CM frame the D(D,n)3He is about 24% more favored.